# cronjob syntax wont work in plesk 12.5

Tags: cron, plesk

I have a problem with the problem with syntax of a cronjob in plesk 12.5 , I use the following syntax in plesk 12.0 and it runs fine, however in plesk 12.5  it won't work.

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassword database | gzip > /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/backupmysql/backup$( date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d_\%H_\%M" ).sql.gz
```

can anybody help me with the correct syntac for plesk 12.5

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

/usr/bin/mysqldump -u user -ppassword database | gzip > /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/backupmysql/backup$( date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d_\%H_\%M" ).sql.gz

At least command like

/usr/bin/mysqldump -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa | gzip > /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/backup$( date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d_\%H_\%M" ).sql.gz

works like a charm.

Comment: plesk gives me the following erros when trying to use: /usr/bin/mysqldump -u user -ppassword database | gzip > /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/backupmysql/backup$( date +"\%Y_\%m_\%d_\%H_\%M" ).sql.gz

-: /usr/bin/mysqldump: No such file or directory
-: date: command not found
-: date: command not found
-: /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/bupmysql/backup.sql.gz: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

> > date: command not found -: date: command not found

Make sure that you have /bin/date installed, it is part of coreutils package.